# How to make one node as owner of particular entry in infinispan distribution mode?

Tags: infinispan

I am currently working on project with infinispan 8.1.3. I want to make sure that the node who created object must be owner of that entry all the time in distribution mode .Is there any option to meet my requirement??. I heard the flag LOCAL_MODE.but, it stores entry in local only .I dont know if that node down, local cahe entry will be shared to another node??. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't use flags unless you exactly know what you're doing. `Flag.CACHE_MODE_LOCAL` means that you won't execute any RPC when doing that operation, but in case that the key does not route to this node, a write will result in a noop and read will return `null`.

It's not possible to tie the entry to the node exclusively - what would you do if this node crashes?

However, if the cluster is stable enough, there's the [Key Affinity Service](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#KeyAffinityService) that will give you a key that belongs to this node. See next chapter about grouping, too, it might fit your use case.

**EDIT**: Instead moving data to the executing node, you can move the execution towards the data. With [Grouping API](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#grouping) you can find the data by the group, using

```
Address owningNode = cache.getAdvancedCache().getDistributionManager()
   .getCacheTopology().getDistributionInfo(group).primary();
ClusterExecutor executor = cache.getCacheManager().executor()
   .filterTargets(Collections.singleton(owningNode));
executor.submit(...)
```

Comment: thanks, i tested with  Key Affinity Service. but, if any node down and again up , the ownersip of data  got change. i have to try grouping api, is there any example program for  grouping api?? . infinispan doc  is not very much information about grouping api

Comment: The doc contains the configuration example, and the rest is just bulk read by group name (AdvancedCache.getGroup()) and bulk removal.

Comment: I have one cache called "jobs"  .i used to put voip call information in jobs cache using callid as  key.here which node put new entry in that cache first time, they must be owner of all the time. i could test this scenenerio in Key Affinity Service as , Object newKey =keyAffinityService.getKeyForAddress(localNodeAddress);jobs.put(newKey,job);  but In grouping api, i dont know where to start . how to create group??   how to force one new entry to that group??

Comment: A discussion could be better suited for forum: https://developer.jboss.org/en/infinispan

Comment: Grouping API is not supposed to put your data to a particular node, rather hold some data together. It's not possible to realize your requirement in Infinispan right now, unless you disable rebalances (then, new joining nodes wouldn't be able to store any data and you could lose the data if more nodes crash).

Comment: @Flavius does grouping api supports replication.

Comment: @karthikeyan Yes. Grouping API keeps the keys together - in the same segment. The segment is always held on numOwner (in dist mode) or all nodes (replicated mode).

Comment: Thank You @Flavius .I want an programmatic example of grouping api,Do you know a place that i could find it out.